# Сборка Qt6 Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: qt, git, qt5

Нужен Qt WebEngineCore:  Proprietary Codecs - yes. Не собирается с такими ошибками

```
./../../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/v8/src/objects/intl-objects.cc:2745:10: error: ‘UNUM_APPROXIMATELY_SIGN_FIELD’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘UNUM_APPROXIMATELY_SIGN_SYMBOL’?
 2745 |     case UNUM_APPROXIMATELY_SIGN_FIELD:
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |          UNUM_APPROXIMATELY_SIGN_SYMBOL
```

и

```
./../../../../../../qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/v8/src/objects/js-number-format.cc:913:43: error: ‘incrementExact’ is not a member of ‘icu_70::number::Precision’
  913 |     precision = ::icu::number::Precision::incrementExact(
      |                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[14/808] CXX obj/v8/v8_base_without_compiler/v8_base_without_compiler_jumbo_58.o
```

Как настроить сборку?

Answer (score 0):

6.4 собирается без ошибок. 6.5 требует icu > 72

Comment: Он Вам нужен? Можно флаг соответствующий убрать - под 20.04 я собирал qtbase и сталкивался с подобной ошибкой. Убрал требование ICU и все собралось.

Comment: там хром с ним линкуется, а не qt.